# Cycle through permutations of a list and apply a function to them

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to get a list of permutations of the 5 airport inputs to go through the distance calculation and do a calculation for each permutation.

```
from airports import *
from math import *
import itertools

dicts=TravelLookUp()
dicts.dictAirport('airport.csv')
dicts.dictCurrency('countrycurrency.csv')
dicts.dictCurrencyRates('currencyrates.csv')

#print(airportdict.airportDict)
#airportdict.airportDict[] IS DICTIONARY

#print(test)

#print(AirportDict)
test= dicts.airportDict['DUB'].getLat()
print(test)

airportList=[]
airportHome=[]
airport1=input('Choose the first airport: ').upper()
airport2=input('Choose the second airport: ').upper()
airport3=input('Choose the third airport: ').upper()
airport4=input('Choose the fourth airport: ').upper()
airport5=input('Choose the fifth airport: ').upper()

airportHome=[airport1]
airportList=[airport2,airport3,airport4,airport5]

AirportCombinations = itertools.permutations(airportList,r=4)

def distance(airport1,airport2):
    distacnces=[]
    lat1=dicts.airportDict[airport1].getLat()
    long1=dicts.airportDict[airport1].getLong()
    lat2=dicts.airportDict[airport2].getLat()
    long2=dicts.airportDict[airport2].getLong()
    lat1R= (lat1*pi/180)
    long1R=(long1*pi/180)
    lat2R=(lat2*pi/180)
    long2R=(long2*pi/180)
    distance= acos(sin(lat1R)*sin(lat2R)*cos(long1R-long2R))*6373
    distances.append(distance)
    return distances

for i in AirportCombinations:
    i=list(i)
    route=[airportHome]
    for value in range(len(i)):
            route.append(value)
            totaldistance=0
            for i in range(len(route)-1):
                legcost=distance(route[i],route[i+1])
                totaldistance+=distance
                print(totaldistance)

distance()
```

The route list holds the permutations and and I want it to cycle through the `distance(airport1,airport2)` function for each of airport pairs in each of the permutations.

Whenever I run this, it only calculates the distance between the same two airports 24 times, and what I want it to do is calculate the distance for every combinations.

How do I get it to calculate run all permutations through the `distance(airport1,airport2)` function? And then create a list to hold all of these calculations?

Comment: what do u mean by 'get all permutations' ? how many do u expect ?

Comment: Well the user inputs 5 airports, 4 of those go to the airport list. this is then put through AirportCombinations = itertools.permutations(airportList,r=4) and should give the following.

Comment: [('DUB', 'SYD', 'AAL', 'LDN'), ('DUB', 'SYD', 'LDN', 'AAL'), ('DUB', 'AAL', 'SYD', 'LDN'),
        ('DUB', 'AAL', 'LDN', 'SYD'), ('DUB', 'LDN', 'SYD', 'AAL'), ('DUB', 'LDN', 'AAL', 'SYD'),
        ('SYD', 'DUB', 'AAL', 'LDN'), ('SYD', 'DUB', 'LDN', 'AAL'), ('SYD', 'AAL', 'DUB', 'LDN'),
        ('SYD', 'AAL', 'LDN', 'DUB'), ('SYD', 'LDN', 'DUB', 'AAL'), ('SYD', 'LDN', 'AAL', 'DUB'),
        ('AAL', 'DUB', 'SYD', 'LDN'), ('AAL', 'DUB', 'LDN', 'SYD'), ('AAL', 'SYD', 'DUB', 'LDN'),
         ('AAL', 'SYD', 'LDN', 'DUB'), ('AAL', 'LDN', 'DUB', 'SYD'),]

Comment: these are then changed from tubules into lists by     for i in AirportCombinations:
        i=list(i)      I want to know how do i get all those permutations from i=list(i)  to run through the def distance function in a loop

Comment: 4! = 24 , and u r getting 24 , what do u need then ?

Comment: So far it is only doing the one calculation 24 times, aka the airportHome=[airport1] * first airport in the AirportCombinations

Comment: Why are you using itertools.permutations? It sounds like itertools.combinations is what you want. ._.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over complicating things somewhat in your loop starting `for i in AirportCombinations`.

I've simplified that loop (and renamed your variables for clarity), but kept your method i.e. converting to a list for each route.

You also had a typo: `totaldistance += distance` should have been `totaldistance += legcost`, I think.

```
for sub_route in AirportCombinations:
    route = [airportHome] + list(sub_route)
    totaldistance = 0
    for i in range(len(route)-1):
        legcost = distance(route[i], route[i+1])
        totaldistance += legcost
    
    #I've un-indented this so it prints for each permutation
    print('route ' + str(route) + ' has distance ' + str(totaldistance)) 

    # Add the distance to a list or dictionary here if you want them available later...
```

---

#### Another method

You can get rid of the inner loop altogether, it's left to the reader which part of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is more important - this is flatter (better than nested), but does that trump "readability counts"...

The zip makes use of the [documented behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip):

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted

```
for sub_route in AirportCombinations:
    route = [airportHome] + list(sub_route)
    totaldistance = sum(distance(a[0], a[1]) for a in zip(route, route[1:]))        
    print('route ' + str(route) + ' has distance ' + str(totaldistance)) 

    # Add the distance to a list or dictionary here if you want them available later...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
for i in AirportCombinations:
    i=list(i)
    route=[airportHome]        
    for value in range(len(i)): <<<
            route.append(value) <<<
            totaldistance=0
            for i in range(len(route)-1):
                legcost=distance(route[i],route[i+1])
                totaldistance+=distance
                print(totaldistance)
```

You are appending `value` to `route` when you should be appending `i[value]`

Or better still, just iterate through `i` directly:

```
for i in AirportCombinations:
    i=list(i)
    route=[airportHome]
    for value in i:
            route.append(value)
            totaldistance=0
            for i in range(len(route)-1):
                legcost=distance(route[i],route[i+1])
                totaldistance+=distance
                print(totaldistance)
```

P.S. - Using `i` in two levels of a nested loop is just confusing...